# Solr json facet api - specify limit

Tags: json, solr, facet

I am using solr 5.1.0. I am trying to use solr json facet api. At the moment i am specifying

`json.facet={"condition_facet":{"terms":"condition"}}`

However this only lists 10 results which is the default limit.
How to get all results for this facet as SOLR 5.1.0 do not understand the flatter json facet structure.

Comment: Found the solution. The query should be                                                         json.facet={"condition_facet":{"terms":{field :"condition_facet",limit:-1}}}

Comment: You can mark your own answer as "accepted", if you write one first.

Answer (score -2):

Using limit and offset parameters together, you can achieve pagination to get all results.

[This link might help you out](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/#TermsFacet)